# Is there a way to combine multiple fields in a select query after where?

Tags: vb.net, select, field, where-clause

This is the query I'm using in vb.net

```
select *
from tbl_patientinfo
where fname like '%" & txtsearchquery.Text & "%'
    or mname like '%" & txtsearchquery.Text & "%'
    or lname like '%" & txtsearchquery.Text & "%'
```

I know it's long, and what I want to know is if there is a way to shorten it. I've tried IN, but it doesn't allow multiple columns, only the search variable. Also it doesn't go well with LIKE. I'm looking for a way to make my code look like this:

```
select *
from tbl_patientinfo
where (fname, mname, lname) like '%" txtsearchquery.text "&'
```

Comment: As Neolisk wrote, there is nothing wrong with the first version of your query. It is obvious what it is intended to do and will be easy to modify later if necessary.

Comment: Maybe there's nothing wrong with it, but still if there's a way to shorten it then I'm interested. I tend to study the hows and whys of almost everything, that and I can use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate the fields.
In MySQL you can do it like this:

```
select *
from tbl_patientinfo
where concat(fname, mname, lname) like '%" & txtsearchquery.text & "%'
```

Comment: This works exactly like what I wanted! Thanks. But to be sure, are there any downsides to concat? It's my first time seing this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a valid VB.NET LINQ. As suggested by another member, it might be MySQL. If this is the case, please adjust your question tags accordingly.

Regardless of the query language, there is nothing wrong with having your WHERE condition like that. Just make sure you are using parameters, to avoid SQL injection. You could have a for loop adding LIKE conditions to the list. Here is what I mean:

```
Dim sql = "select * from tbl_patientinfo where "
Dim conditions As New List(Of String)
For Each fieldName As String In {"fname", "mname", "lname"}
  conditions.Add(fieldName & " LIKE '%" & txtsearchquery.Text & "%'")
Next
sql &= String.Join(" OR ", conditions.ToArray())
```

This way you keep your code DRY (avoid duplication), and don't depend on the vendor.

If you decide to use parameters, should be an easy modification of the above code.

Comment: sorry if I forgot to mention this was MySql.